# Interface as a method's parameter

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-inner-class

I have a problem with naming following situation

```
{...}

X.a;
a.addListener( new ListenerForX(){
// some interface methods
});

{...}
```

It is the same as:

```
{...} 
X.a;
a.addListener( new XListener());
{...} 
private class XListener implements ListenerForX{
//some methods
}
```

How is it called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first code example is called [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Both examples are valid in Java. The method is just interested in `ListenerForX` and doesn't care about the implementation thereof.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is an anonymous inner class.

Say you have an interface `Walkable` with `doWalk ()` ,

For a method that takes in a Walkable instance you could write something like .

```
takeForaWalk(new Walkable() {
 void doWalk() {
 //Impl
}}
)
```